# Ajax call for loading friends & displaying on a profile page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Trying figure this ajax stuff out - I'm new to it.  Right now I have a profile page that's set up in tabs. [image: Profile Page Tabs].

Under the friends tab I have limited the display to 5 on default.  [image: 5 friends displayed on default]

This is done easily enough using the following code.

```
<?php 
global $con;

$username = $_GET['profile_username'];

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username' LIMIT 0,5"); 
?>

<div class="panel-body">
<ul>
    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $friends = $row['profile_pic']; 
        $friend_username = $row['username'];
    ?>
  <li><a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="<?php echo $friend_username; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $friends; ?>" title="<?php echo $friend_username; ?>"></a></li><?php } ?>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="ViewAllFriends" 
name="ViewAllFriends" value="View All Friends">
</div>
```

Originally I had the View all friends button call another query that displayed all of the friends and this worked great, however the page refreshed & in doing so switches over to the About tab which I've set as active.

I thought I would try ajax to make this call so the page wouldn't be refreshed, however being new to this I'm having some problems.  Here's what I have:

```
         function ajaxfriends(){

        $.ajax({

            url:'includes/handlers/ajax_load_profile_friends.php',
            type:'POST',
            success: function(response){

            }
        });
      }
```

In ajax_load_profile_friends.php I have:

```
 require '../../config/config.php';
 include("../classes/User.php");

        $username = $_GET['profile_username'];

        if(isset($_POST['ViewAllFriends'])) {
            //Query to run if button ViewAllFriends submitted
            $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username'");
```

I have the function `ajaxfriends()` being called by `onclick=` on the View all friends button.  Right now I`m not getting any errors but the button is also not doing anything.  Again, I'm new to ajax so I know this is where the problem lies; any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

The page is refreshing because the button is of type `submit`. Change that to type `<input type="button"` or `<button type="button">`

You also might need to kill the event if the page is still doing something aside from what the button is intended to do. so, instead of binding directly to the `onclick` attribute, you can bind in the js

```
$('#ViewAllFriends').click(function(e){
    // The click event to the button will only trigger this function
    // and stop here (not trigger other functions bound to this event)
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Your code here
    ajaxfriends();
});
```

Comment: I've made these changes, the page doesn't refresh now, but the button is not displaying all of the user friends.  It just clicks dead.

Comment: You have to update your `ajaxfriends()` function to add the handler for the ajax response. If that is your current code, then it is empty and does nothing (`success: function(response){

            }`). You have to update the friends list manually based from your ajax response

Comment: Thanks Kyle, figured it out.